# Zend Framework: How to read email attachments (and save to disk)?

Tags: php, zend-framework, imap, email-attachments, zend-mail

I am currently using Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap to read email messages using IMAP. I am able to read the email body (text and html) thanks to the documentation.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to save email attachments. I can't find anything that explains how to convert the raw content and save the attachments. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

http://macfoo.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/save-an-email-attachment-using-zend-mail/

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/function-extract-email-attachments-php-imap/

Answer (score 0):

I found that reading emails using Zend_Mail can be a little buggy. Sometimes not all of the attachment files are recognized or in some cases imap can't even decode the body of the email .

We're using [Sendgrid service](http://sendgrid.com/documentation/display/api/Parse) to parse emails now, and it's working pretty well. They have a special api to decode emails. on the downside, it cost money, but I prefer better results.

Comment: good to know. we've actually been considering adding SendGrid to our application as well.